# Rails show the user who posted the post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

So I am building an app, I have a user model managed by devise, and a post model, post belongs_to user and user has_many posts, now I have a page where I show all posts

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <div id="post">
        <%= post.user.name%> 
        <%= post.course_name %>
        <%= post.course_number %>
        <%= image_tag post.user.image_string %>
        <% if  post.user == current_user%>
            <%= link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(post) %>
            <%= link_to "Delete", post_path(post), method: :DELETE, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }  %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
<% end%>

<%= link_to "profile", '/posts/profile' %>
```

What I want to do is click on the image of the user above, and it should take me to his profile. I thought about the following : 
Create an action:

```
def show_profile
end
```

Then in the `show_profile.html.erb` I would say :

```
<%=@post.user.name %>
```

in my routes I would add :

```
get '/posts/show_profile'
```

then I would add  `<%=link_to image_tag post.user.image_string, posts_show_profile_path(post) %>`

Would this work? is this the best I can do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
<%= link_to current_user do%>
  <%= image_tag post.user.image_string %>
<% end %>
```

This will direct you to User's show page, where you can show user's profile.

If you want to display it for other users, u may define route for it, as

```
get "profile/:id" => "users#show", :as => 'profile'

<%= link_to profile_path(@user.id) do%>
  <%= image_tag post.user.image_string %>
<% end %>
```

And in UsersController, define your show action as,

```
#users_controller.rb
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: But I don't want to show the current_user profile, I want to show the profile of the user who posted the post.

Comment: Thanks Leo, I am yet to try it but the answer matches my question.

Comment: yes, you are right, because, it is the right way to do it. :)

Comment: I m getting this error when I add the above route : You should not use the `match` method in your router without specifying an HTTP method. If you want to expose your action to both GET and POST, add `via: [:get, :post]` option. If you want to expose your action to GET, use `get` in the router: Instead of: match "controller#action" Do: get "controller#action"

Comment: it depends on your rails version.. Use "get" instead of "match" in your route

Comment: yup that did the trick, thanks for your help man, really appreciate it.

Comment: It is my pleasure dude :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code will work perfectly you just need to modify 'show_profile' action a bit like this -

```
def show_profile
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
```

This way you can get @post object on `show_profile.html.erb` to show -

```
<%=@post.user.name %>
```

Alternatively you can pass user object in place of `@post` to show user profile -

```
def show_profile
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @user = @post.user
end
```

and in `show_profile.html.erb` -

```
<%=@user.name %>
```